# Custom List forms not working after migration from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I had a site working in SP2010. There were lists with custom list forms in the site. 
However, after migration to SP2013, the sharepoint fields on the custom list forms (New/Edit) are not getting rendered. What is the problem?

Comment: Old thread but I will still post one solution in case some one else is having the same issue and searching. I had the same issue with all custom list forms. I open up site in SharePoint designer , Delete the old forms , created new forms for new edit and display and it worked. Wonder how can I avoid this from the beginning. so will not have to go to each list after migration ?

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem .I am facing the same issue currently. The forms are ok in SD2013 but when i view them in browser they are completely different with lots of custom codes missing .Is it something to do with the master pages controls?